# How to get specific data (text) from other website using JavaScript (Vanilla)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, get, fetch-api

I'm still a newbie and I'm trying to retrieve data from a website to put it in my project. The site is online radio and i need to get what's playing right now. All the possible answers which i found here are using jQuery but I need it in Vanilla JS.

Website url - https://www.radionova.bg/schedule/index

What should i use to get the information so i can put it into a variable and then change innerHtml of the element in my project?

Comment: Read the documentation of `fetch()`.